# Passing boolean method from one class to another

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I have 2 java files called CastlingCheck.java and Board.java. The CastlingCheck.java contains a boolean method(testCastling) in which I would like to call upon within the Board.java.

CastlingCheck.java:

```
package chess;
public class CastlingCheck extends Board{
public boolean testCastling(int oldX, int oldY, int newX, int newY) {
    int deltax = newX - oldX;
    if (1st condition) {
    **code here**
        return true;
            }

    if (2nd condition) {
    **code here**
        return true;
            }

    if (3rd condition) {
    **code here**
        return true;
            }

    if (4thnd condition) {
    **code here**
        return true;
            }

    return false;
    }
}
```

Board.java:

```
package chess;
...code...

public boolean testCastling(int oldx, int oldy, int newx, int newy) {
    return true;
}

...code...
```

Am I doing it right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In OO-programming, your goal is to mimic the real world.

So first of all, ask yourself this question: is a CastlingCheck a Board ?

The answer is: no, it is not. So CastlingCheck is not a Board.

In OO, this kind of question is called inheritance, programmed with the extends keyword.

So, CastlingCheck should not extend Board.

To fix your problem now, make an instace of the CastlingCheck class and call the method.

So in the Board class:

```
CastlingCheck cc = new CastlingCheck(); 
boolean b = cc.testCastling(...);
```

However you should better follow some design principles like the well-known MVC. There is plenty of info on the Internet for this.

Comment: CastlingCheck is not a Board. I know. CastlingCheck is just a class which holds a method that I would like to call upon in the Board class. Also, isn't it supposed to be `boolean b = cc.textCastling(0,0,0,0)`?@StefaanNeyts